# Quick way to open a file in the Code Blocks project?

Tags: codeblocks

The problem is that, I use Code Blocks to edit my code. And use the Doxygen to build the documents.

When I build the documents, the Doxygen create some warning message in the Doxygen main window like this:

```
D:/WorkSpace/iSource/libdata/inc/hw_data_redblack_tree.h:67: warning: unable to resolve reference to `rbtree_example' for \ref command
D:/WorkSpace/iSource/libdata/inc/hw_data_redblack_tree.h:127: warning: argument 'pItem' of command @param is not found in the argument list of RBTree_AddItem(RBTree *pTree, NodeItem item)
```

And I want to correct the code to avoid the warning, so I need to open the file which the Doxygen warning me. So I copy the file name which is `hw_data_redblack_tree.h` in the example warning message, and want open it in the Code Blocks.

But I don't how to open the file which the name in my clipboard in Code Blocks.

I try copy all the file path to my clipboard and use `Ctrl + O` to open the file directly, I get the error message:

```
[Window Title]
Open file

[Content]
D:/WorkSpace/iSource/libdata/inc/hw_data_redblack_tree.h
The file name is invalid.

[OK]
```

Currently, I have to find the file in the project browser and then open it by double click it. But, there are too many files in the project, it's to slow to find it.

Does anyone know the quick way to open the file? 
Please help me, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found a way by myself.
Use `Ctrl + G` to find file, and paste the file name, can quickly open the file which in the project.